# Receiving req.body empty with post form with Express node.js

Tags: forms, node.js, post, express

I've got a simply form, that sends POST data to my Node.JS server, with Express. This is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="/sendmessage">
  <div class="ui-widget">
      <input type="text" id="search" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div>
  <textarea id="message"></textarea>
</form>
```

The ui-widget and the input is releated with `typehead`, an autocomplete library from Twitter.
And this is how I handle the POST request in the server:

```
app.post('/sendmessage', function (req, res){

  console.log(req.body);

  usermodel.findOne({ user: req.session.user }, function (err, auser){

        if (err) throw err;

        usermodel.findOne({ user: req.body.search }, function (err, user){

            if (err) throw err;

             var message = new messagemodel({

                  fromuser: auser._id,
                  touser: user._id,
                  message: req.body.message,
                  status: false

             });

             message.save(function (err){

                  if (err) throw err;

                  res.redirect('/messages')

             })

        });

   });

});
```

The console shows me '{}', and then an error with `req.body.search`, because `search` is not defined. I don't know what is happening here, and it's not a problem related with the `typehead` input. Any solution for this problem...?

Thank's advance!

Comment: I would add in console checks everywhere to check what `req.body` is outputting as well, if `req.body` is empty then I would look at what is wrong with how/what you are passing to `/sendmessage`

Comment: Try adding a `name="search"` attribute to your input field.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`req.body` is made up of names and values.

add `name="search"` on your search box and try again.

You also must use the express/connect.bodyParser() middleware, thanks Nick Mitchinson!

Comment: Also, I would ensure that you have used the Express/Connect bodyParser. If not, Express will not populate the req.body object.

Comment: I was banging my head for why, my request.body is empty and then realized, that my inputs should have name. Classic fool :D. Thank you..

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem and it turned out I was using `app.use(express.bodyParser());` but it was after the code I was using. Moving it up solved the issue.

Comment: Very important answer - Express is very finnicky about location of anything in the app.use() configuration object. I encountered the problem where app.use(express.bodyParrser()) didn't work because I was declaring my routes from an external file, and initializing them before calling app.use(express.bodyParser())

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly my issue :)

Answer (score 6):

on **express 4** would be this one. *(note that this will not parse multipart/uploads).*

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

and if you want to receive json input

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by my app redirecting `http` to `https`.
Updating Facebook to use the `https` uri fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did not provide name tags like this `name="firstname"` in my `input` field. After adding them, everything worked.